# dereference a pointer to a pointer to a structure

Tags: c, pointers, structure, operator-precedence

```
gcc 4.7.2
c89
```

Hello,

I am trying to dereference a pointer to a pointer to a structure, and I get this error message when I do the following:

```
LOG_INFO("CHANNEL ID --- %d", *channel->id);
```

Compile error

```
request for member ‘id’ in something not a structure or union
```

If I try and cast it to the correct pointer type, I still get the same error message:

```
LOG_INFO("CHANNEL ID --- %d", (*(channel_t*)channel->id));
```

I solved the problem by declaring a new variable and assigning the address of where the structure is pointing to:

```
channel_t *ch = NULL;
ch = *channel;
LOG_INFO("CHANNEL ID --- %d", ch->id);
```

I am just wondering why the first two methods failed.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

structure:

```
typedef struct tag_channel channel_t;
struct tag_channel {
    size_t id;
    char *name;
};
```

The way I am calling it:

```
channel_t *channel = NULL;
channel = (channel_t*)apr_pcalloc(mem_pool, sizeof *channel);
LOG_CHECK(job_queue_pop(queue, &channel) == TRUE, "Failed to pop from the queue");
```

And the function, I am having trouble with:

```
apr_status_t job_queue_pop(apr_queue_t *queue, channel_t **channel)
{
    apr_status_t rv = 0;
    channel_t *ch = NULL;

    rv = apr_queue_pop(queue, (void**)channel);
    if(rv != APR_SUCCESS) {
        char err_buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
        LOG_ERR("Failed to pop from the queue %s", apr_strerror(rv, err_buf, BUFFER_SIZE));

        return FALSE;
    }

    ch = *channel;  
    LOG_INFO("CHANNEL ID --- %d", ch->id);
    LOG_INFO("CHANNEL NAME - %s", ch->name);

    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the operator precedence wrong. `->` operator has a higher precedence than `.` operator. So `->` is evaluated before `.` making it `*(channel->id)` which is wrong.

Look at the following code. It works fine.

```
typedef struct test_
{
   int i;
}test;

int main()
{
   test a;
   test *aptr = &a;
   test **aptrptr = &aptr;
   a.i=6;
   printf("\n%d\n",(*aptrptr)->i);
   return 0;
}
```

**Read about precedence [here](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm).**

Answer (score 4):

You have the precedence wrong, it should be e.g.

```
(*channel)->id
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an error due to [operator precendece](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence).
Try this:

```
(*channel)->id
```

the operator `"*"` is evaluated after the operator `"->"`.