# How to access memebers of a reference to a reference to a struct. (struct**)

Tags: c

I'm very new to C programming. And I'm asking myself how I can access mebers of double referenced structs. (Not sure if you even would name it like this.)

So having this simple example:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char n[4];
} inner;
typedef struct {
    inner inner[5];
} outer;


int main(void)
{
    outer o;
    strcpy(o.inner[0].n, "123");
    strcpy(o.inner[1].n, "ABC");
    
    // Working. Prints "123".
    printf("%s\n", o.inner[0].n);
    
    outer* oo = &o;
    
    // Working. Prints "123".
    printf("%s\n", oo->inner[0].n);
    
    outer** ooo = &oo;
    
    // Not working. Need help here, please.
    printf("%s\n", *ooo->inner[0].n);
    
    return 0;
}
```

How can I access members of `outer** ooo`. I tried something in the last printf statement, but is not working.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `(*ooo)->inner[0].n` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dereference a pointer to a pointer to a structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435504/dereference-a-pointer-to-a-pointer-to-a-structure)

Comment: Unfortunatley still gives an error: `error: ‘*ooo’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?`

Comment: No, it doesn't give that error https://godbolt.org/z/zndEnEYd9

Comment: Oh, sorry. I placed the '*' outside of the parentheses while I was trying your suggestion. You are right. this is working.

Comment: Alternative syntax for `(*ooo)->inner[0].n` is `ooo[0]->inner[0].n` but perhaps that would cause confusion because `ooo` is not pointing to the first element of an array. It works because the address of a non-array object, e.g. `(&oo)` can be treated like a single-element array.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This would also work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Ted Lyngmo and @Ian Abbott.
The correct answers are:

`(*ooo)->inner[0].n`

or

`ooo[0]->inner[0].n`